# Sending Post Request Twitter Using Restify

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, restify

I am using restify to send request to twitter. But when I send post request to get `request_token`. I get following response. This is because there is no `oauth: requestTokenOauth` in body.

> How I send post request? What is wrong I am doing?

[restify-clients](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-clients#postpath-object-callback).

**My Response**

```
{
      "errors": [
        {
          "code": 215,
          "message": "Bad Authentication data."
        }
      ]
    }
```

**My Code**

```
var requestTokenUrl = '/oauth/request_token';
     var accessTokenUrl = '/oauth/access_token';
     var profileUrl = '/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json';

        var client = restify.createJsonClient({ url : 'https://api.twitter.com' });

        if (!req.body.oauth_token || !req.body.oauth_verifier) {
            var requestTokenOauth = {
                callback: 'http://social.int/',
                consumer_key: 'twitter-app-key', 
                consumer_secret: 'twitter-app-secret',
            };

            // Step 1. Obtain request token for the authorization popup.
            client.post( requestTokenUrl ,{oauth: requestTokenOauth}, function(error , request, response , body){
                var oauthToken = body;
                res.send(oauthToken);
            });
        }
```